# MemoryError while writing large binary file

Tags: python, binary, byte, buffer

All of the related questions i researched involved reading from a file and writing to another. I am generating a large file from scratch. I'll simplify it here:

```
import os

fo = open("example.example", "wb", 0)

fo.write ((b'\x01\x01\x01\x01')+(((b'\xff') * 1074000000)+ (b'\x01\x01\x01\x01;')))

fo.close()
```

This example should create a file a little larger that a gig... I know I need to use buffer during writing process, but not sure how when simply writing from scratch in bytes. THANKS IN ADVANCE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking Python to create more than 1074000000 bytes in memory. This logically causes `MemoryError`.

```
import os

with open("example.example", "wb") as f:
    f.write(b'\x01\x01\x01\x01')
    for i in xrange(1074000000):
        f.write(b'\xff')
    f.write(b'\x01\x01\x01\x01;')
```

Of course, you can write the data in the loop in bigger chunks to make it more effective, but now you shall have the idea.

In case you use Python 3, replace `xrange` with `range`.

Using `range` in Python 2 could be a problem, as it would attempt to create an array of 1074000000 integers in memory. `xrange` instead creates a generator, which is returning the numbers one by one, but not recreating them in advance. This has became standard practice in Pyton 3 and `xrange` was removed in favour of `range`.

Comment: @ Jan Vlcinsky  Thanks You... one quick question...when i try your advice, i get this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/testpython/scripts/example.py", line 5, in <module>
    for i in xrange(107400):
NameError: name 'xrange' is not defined

Comment: @user3157868 My code is for Python 2.7. If you use Python 3, use `range` instead.

Comment: @ Jan Vlinsky That worked like a charm, thank you! I'll look into the chunk method you mentioned if it will speed things up. THANKS